# GridView.FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I want that when I click on an element of GridView displayed letter, which I clicked. But initially I got here error when I wanted to take the position of the element. If I understood correctly, gridview does not see the textview, but i don't know why.

Error:

```
5312-5312/standandroid.ru.words E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:240)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:131)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:273)
        at standandroid.ru.words.MainActivity$1$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1130)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2818)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3498)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
        at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView txt, textTV;
EditText etxt;
Button btn;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
GridView gridView;
String name;

char c;
ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();

int i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    etxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            name = etxt.getText().toString();
            TreeSet list = new TreeSet();
            for (i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
                c = name.charAt(i);
                list.add(c);

            }
             arrayList = new ArrayList(list);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, R.id.tv, arrayList);
            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridmain);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ViewGrid();
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

    });}
  private void ViewGrid(){
    gridView.setNumColumns(4);
    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH); }}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="175dp" />

<EditText

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5S93.png

Comment: Can you post your xml file? What is line 70 in MainActivity? Also try and define `gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridmain);` outside the `onClickListener` where you've defined others.

Comment: 70line- Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohh! I see, the issue is that `Toast` is thinking of `position` as a `resourceID`. If you see [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) specs here, you would see that you can define `resourceId` or a `CharSequence`. So make sure you are passing the position as a `String`. Something like:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```